# Laravel foreign key not working as intended

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I am having trouble with Laravel's foreign key. Each user has his own posts, so when the user is logged in he can manage his posts (edit or delete them). When the logged in user creates a post it is stored in the posts table with a foreign key "user_id" containing the current logged in user's id.
users table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('role')->nullable();
            $table->integer('times_donated')->default(0);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('profile_picture')->nullable();
            $table->string('background_picture')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

posts table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('blood_type');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->string('contact_info');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
};
```

user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'description',
        'role',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    // relationship with posts
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

post model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // relationship to user
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

create post leads to this controller method:

```
// store post data
    public function store(PostRequest $request){
        $formFields = $request->validated();
        $formFields['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        
        Post::create($formFields);
    }
```

API route:

```
// create post
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store']);
```

I am a beginner in Laravel and was expecting it to work since I was following a YouTube tutorial. When I create a post it successfully gets added to the posts table but with a "user_id" = null. I think it has something to do with the nullable property on the foreign key, because in the tutorial he didn't add nullable to the foreign key and it worked but when I did it it gave an error (General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value).

Comment: `Auth::id() ` what does it return? are you sure the user is authorized and the route is protected from guests?

Comment: make sure there's a user `Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);`

Comment: `user_id` isn't fillable, can't be mass assigned, on the Post model

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the user_id to fillable in the Post Model to mass assign it

```
protected $fillable = [
'user_id',
'username',
'blood_type',
'status',
'contact_info',
'description'
];
```

if you don't add it it will take the database default value for each column

also don't forget to add the auth middleware to the route

```
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])
->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);
```

otherwise the `Auth::id()` will return null also